# Retrive image asset absolute url using Twig in Drupal 8

Tags: url, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am getting the absolute url path for an image using Twig function `<{{ url(<'front'>) }}`in Drupal 8 and it just works fine. Problem comes when  changing the default language (en) to (sp), then the url changes from localhost/themes/.../image.png to localhost/sp/themes/.../image.png and then the image is no longer available. I think there is an option to pass the language as a parameter to the url function, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that.
Many thanks for your help

**Update**

I have to try this

`{{ absolute_url(asset('images/logo.png')) }}`

I will test and comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue first installing Tweak module in your Drupal installation and using drupal_url Tweak function like this:

`{{ drupal_url('<front>', {}, {'language': 'en' }) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [twig tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and it's [file URL](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#file-url) function.

```
{{ 'public://images/logo.png'|file_url(false) }}
```

Comment: Hey 2pha, finally solved using Drupal Tweak module, then you can use {{ drupal_url('<front>', {}, { 'language' : 'en' }) }}. Thanks for your answer